# Creating Custom URLs in Next.js with Next.js Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I am working on a Next.js application with an app directory structure. In my application, I have a page called itemDetail that displays the details of a specific item. However, I want to customize the URL so that it looks like /items?search=[id] instead of the default /itemDetail/[id].

I have tried using Next.js Router's rewrites() function in my next.config.js as follows:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/items?search=:id',
        destination: '/itemDetail/:id', 
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

In my itemList page, I am using the following link to navigate to the itemDetail page:

```
// itemList.tsx
import Link from 'next/link';

// Inside the component
<Link href={`/items?search=${item.id}`} >{item.title}</Link>
```

Expected Result:

I expected that when I access the custom URL /items?search=[id], it would properly redirect to the itemDetail page with the corresponding item ID. However, the redirection didn't work as expected, and I encountered issues with the custom URL pattern.

Request for Help:

I would appreciate any help, guidance, or suggestions on how to correctly implement this custom URL pattern using Next.js Router in my app directory structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the itemDetail page, you need to do this:

```js
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const Index = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const search = searchParams.get("search");

  return <div>{search}</div>;
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params
This is the link to the docs for this function if you want to know more.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repository of your project or something?
Or at least a screenshot of your project structure.

Comment: Hi @ugur_sa

Now i'm having this issue:

**http://localhost:3000/itemDetail?search=1234**
**"404 This page could not be found."**
This is the change in itemList:
 
`<Link href={{ pathname: '/itemDetail', query: { search: item.id } }}>{item.title}</Link>`
this is the change in itemDetail:

`import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
export default function ItemDetail() {
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const search = searchParams.get("search");
console.log(search) // i can´t see nothing here
  // return (<div><h1>{itemDetail?.item?.title}</h1></div>);
}`

Comment: This my project structure:
https://ibb.co/dDdJSJ0

What i need change?
i'm using app directory

Comment: You need to remove the [id] folder and move the page.tsx thats inside into itemDetail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
// itemList.tsx
import Link from 'next/link';

// Inside the component
<Link href={{ pathname: '/itemDetail', query: { search: item.id } }}>
  {item.title}
</Link>

// itemDetail.tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const ItemDetail = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { search } = router.query;

  // Use the search parameter to display the details of the item

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item Details:</h1>
      <p>Search: {search}</p>
      {/* Display the details of the item */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemDetail;
```

Comment: Hi! when i try to use useRouter from 'next/router' in itemDetail.tsx i have this issue:

"Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted"

Structure app:  
app.  
├── itemDetail  
│   ├── [id].  
│   │   └── page.tsx  
├── ItemList.  
│   └── page.tsx.         
├── layout.tsx.  
└── page.tsx.

Comment: This will not work with the app router!